# TO_CHAR PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, to-char

I have this query:

```
SELECT hora FROM table;
```

I got "09:45:00"

Now, I'm trying to get the hour from that timestamp, and I'm trying:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hora,'HH24'), hora FROM table;
```

I was expecting: 9 | 09:45:00

But I got this error:

Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function doesn't exist to_char(character varying, unknown)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is `hora` stored? If it’s a string (suggested by `character varying`) you may need to cast it as a time. Have you tried `hora::time`?

Comment: @Manngo it was 5 years ago, can't remember

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('09:45:00'::time,'HH24') ;
```